# Will this LED clock circuit work?

Tags: atmega, multiplexer, atmega328p

I am making a LED wall clock with an ATmega328P Xplained Mini board, 64 LEDs (4 is for the "main ticks" 15,30,45,60) around the PCB to show the seconds, and a 7 segment 4 digits display to show the hours and the minutes.

[image: schematic]

My (beginner) question is:

Will this idea work? I tried to put in enough decoupling capacitors (not sure if needed), but I don't know if something is missing or wrong (the multiplexing maybe)?

Is this the way to wire the buttons and the shift registers?

Comment: On first glance it looks OK. You could improve legibility by eliminating many of the kinks just by moving some blocks around. Oh, and your ground symbols should point to ground. The symbol represents conducting plates buried in the earth. Burying them in the sky is always a little disconcerting.

Comment: "floating" grounds (lol)

Comment: Thank you very much, now I shall continue, and I will pay attention to the placements :)

Comment: This question is too broad for stack exchange and besides seem to be made obsolete by your re-posting at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443737/tpic6c595d-q0-pin-is-always-high